# Is there a way to render a component dynamically in VueJS?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, ionic-vue

I have a component called CanvasComp which I am importing from my components folder. I am rendering this component on my template like `<CanvasComp :jsoData="data"/>`. It is sending the jsonData to the component. What I want is to render this component dynamically without having to display it manually on the template then pass the jsonData dynamically also.Below is my current implementation:

```
<template>
    <ion-page id="main-content">
        <CanvasComp :jsoData="data"/>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent, onBeforeMount, onMounted, ref, watch, watchEffect, reactive, computed  } from "vue";
    import { IonContent,IonPage } from "@ionic/vue";
    import CanvasComp from "@/components/CanvasComp.vue";

    export default defineComponent({
        name: "GraphView",
        components: {
        IonContent,
        IonPage,
        CanvasComp,
    },

    setup() {
        const data= [
            { id: 1, name: 'Default' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Demographics'},
            { id: 3, name: 'Other'},
        ];
    }

    return { data, CanvasComp }
</script>
```

Is there a way I can render that `<CanvasComp :jsoData="data"/>` in my template dynamically while passing the jsonData as well?
e.g `const CanvasComp = prop{jsonData: data};` then return it.

Comment: Is there a function you need in CanvasComp to do something to your json data?  Is that why you want to return it, and maybe render it elsewhere? Maybe reoganizing your code in some way would be a better solution... I'm just confused what the ultimate goal is here. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @yoduh What I want to do is have a canvas component which I will be passing that jsonData to. The json data will be changing and what I want is to recreate this component everytime the data changes to it can then recreate with this new data. I will watch for any changes in a variable called `inputId` and when it changes I will then filter the jsonData to exclude some data and then recreate the component using this said new data

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need, however there is a way how to dynamically render a component into the template:

Lets say we have a simple component `components/HelloWorld.vue` which accepts a `text` prop and renders it in an `<h1>` element:

```js
<template>
  <h1>{{ text }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Now I have another component `components/Wrapper.vue` which uses the `<component>` element to render a dynamic component based on the value of the `dynamicComponent` data property.

```js
<template>
  <component :is="dynamicComponent" :text="dynamicText" />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, markRaw } from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      dynamicComponent: markRaw(HelloWorld),
      dynamicText: 'Hello people!',
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

In the example above the `dynamicComponent` data property is a function that returns the imported `HelloWorld` component, and the `dynamicText` data property is a string with the value `"Hello people!"`. This value will be passed as the `text` prop to the `HelloWorld` component when it's rendered.

**Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-7kdukc?file=src/components/Wrapper.vue) to a working DEMO.**

In your case I imagine you could dynamically render the `CanvasComp` component the same way I have rendered my `HelloWorld` component. And of course, instead of the `text` prop you would use the `jsoData` prop.